# Possible to have damaged wire that beeps on continuity check?

Tags: electrical, car, wiring

I suspect I have a issue on one of the connectors in my harness, so I'm testing the loom for continuity on switches contacts and connector pins etc. following the schematic.

I'm wondering is it possible to have the multimeter beep on the continuity test between two points but also have a bad wire, corroded or something?

Comment: Yes. This can happen often when the wire terminal is cracked or poorly crimped. It can still beep for a continuity check but will come loose or be to little contact to carry much current. Also, its common to push the probe into the harness which pushed the broken connection together giving you a false successful connection.

Comment: Are there any alternative testing methods other than continuity? I'm not that experienced but one thing that comes to mind is to test the wire before the connector, with a needle or something that makes a small puncture that can be fixed easily....but then again this would be problematic if that probing puncture is not sealed back properly.

Comment: Had this happen on a speed sensor. I checked continuity on wires. Replaced with aftermarket sensor and still didn't work. Rechecked wires and still good. Bought OEM sensor, still didn't work until I jiggled the connector. Then it worked. Over $300 for a bad connector.

Comment: @Varonne this would also fail to detect a bad terminal in the harness. Poking the wire in my opinion is probably the least effective. The MOST common failure of the wire is where its crimped to the terminal inside the harness in my experience. You can do continuity check with jiggle and maybe try checking with a load. Something like a 1A lamp.